# Power Bi: Cannot enable SSL for the connection when connecting to a server that has not enabled SSL

Tags: ssl, google-bigquery, powerbi

I am new to PowerBi and I am trying to use it for my project. In the project, I got data from BigQuery google data "NYC cab". The data loaded to the PowerBi for a while (few billion rows) then an error appeared as below. I tried to research about it but none error discussed in the forum was the same as mine. Several posts which also have error with server recommend set SSL certificate on SQL server but I did not use SQL server. With me, I felt that Google Cloud set limit for people to download data for a certain amount of time. I really appreciate if someone could suggest some solutions. 
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you try to oad a smaller amount of data to see if your suspicion is correct? I would not be surprised when you get same error...

Comment: Yeah, the same problem still happen